# Azure Media Services - conference mode

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, video-conferencing

I have been told by Azure sales consultant (online chat) that Azure Media Services support conferencing. I cannot find such option. I see that AMS support online streaming but I'd like also to enable other people to speak.

Anyone has such experience with AMS? Is my scenario possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Azure Communications Services, not Media Services.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/communication-services/

Comment: is there ay roadap of ACS? I assume in MS case it would be preview->beta->stable production. When this product will hit beta release (I need stable API)?

Comment: Here is their [roadmap](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/blob/master/roadmap.md) and [roadmap board](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/projects/1).